# Shouls I use .com or .us

Tags: domains

My website is based in the UK with a .co.uk domain. We are now expanding into the US. I' m wondering whether I should use .com or .us for this domain? If I use .com, will this appear in the UK over my .co.uk domain?

Comment: I think this is mostly a matter of opinion.   Either will work and search engines don't treat them differently.  .com domains are certainly much more common and users are used to them.  .us domains are pretty rare.   On the other hand there may be many more desirable .us domains available to register.

Comment: The other part of your question is answered here: [.co.uk targeted for google.co.uk .com targeted for google.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35953/co-uk-targeted-for-google-co-uk-com-targeted-for-google-com)